# Copying to the clipboard in PowerShell without a new line

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a way to remove a new line from `out-clipboard` or `clip` in PowerShell?

I'm using this code to copy current path to clipboard:

```
function cl() {
    (Get-Location).ToString() | clip
}
```

And every time I use this, a new line is added to the copied text. It's frustrating, because then I can't paste it in the CLI, like I would with text that is copied from elsewhere. Because a new line makes a command on the CLI automatically executed.

Example: I'm in `C:\Users` and type `cl`, and then I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to pass the text, the command is executed, and I can't type any more. But when text is passed without a new line nothing is executed, and I can continue to type.

Comment: Hey IGRACH, would you consider changing the selected answer to BdN3504's? IMHO it's clearly better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @PetSerAl in the comments, the newline is added by PowerShell when the string object is sent through the pipeline. The stringified output of `Get-Location` does not have that trailing newline:

```
PS C:\> $v = (Get-Location).ToString()
PS C:\> "-$v-"
-C:\-
```

You could try something like [this](http://newdelhipowershellusergroup.blogspot.ch/2012/01/sending-text-to-clipboard-everywhere.html):

```psh
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$tb = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$tb.MultiLine = $true
$tb.Text = (Get-Location).ToString()
$tb.SelectAll()
$tb.Copy()
```

Comment: Thank you sir you are a real Santa, best present a had this year xD

Comment: It is not `clip` fault, it is PowerShell adds newlines when sending objects to native commands by pipeline.

Comment: @PetSerAl I don't think it's a PowerShell issue, because the same thing happens in CMD when you do `echo %CD% | clip`, and no newline is added when you do `(Get-Location).ToString() | %{"-$_-"}` in PowerShell.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It is `echo` who add newline here. Create text file with one line and no newline in the end, then type `type test.txt|clip` in `CMD` and see no newline in the end.

Comment: Many are saying that this is not `clip.exe`'s fault. I'm not going to claim anything here but this is the same behavior when executed from WSL bash. I.e. ```pwd | clip.exe```

Answer (score 31):

Use the [`Set-Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard) function:

```
(get-location).ToString()|Set-Clipboard
```

Comment: Brilliant, much neater than the other answers.

Comment: I use this all the time with the Set-Clipboard alias 'scb'

Comment: Using aliases all the way: `(pwd).Path|scb` .  Tested on PS Core 7.1. `Path` works because of [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/PathInfo.cs#L81).

Comment: This should be accepted as the question's answer. I'm a bit annoyed that the author is still active on StackOverflow and constituent communities, yet has not fixed this discrepancy.

Answer (score 7):

```
Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore
$clipText = (get-location).ToString() | Out-String -Stream
[Windows.Clipboard]::SetText($clipText)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ending the string with a null byte will take care of it. Useful for powershell core, which doesn't contain Set-Clipboard

```
function set-clipboard{
    param(
       [parameter(position=0,mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$Text
    )
    begin{
        $data = [system.text.stringbuilder]::new()
    }

    process{
        if ($text){
            [void]$data.appendline($text)
        }
    }

    end{
        if ($data){
            $data.tostring().trimend([environment]::newline) + [convert]::tochar(0) | clip.exe
        }
    }
}


"asdf" | set-clipboard
```